# Can't read swagger JSON from http://localhost:9000/api-docs/

Tags: jhipster, swagger-ui

The api-docs was working fine earlier. It stopped working and now I get

```
Can't read swagger JSON from http://localhost:9000/api-docs/
```

If I change src/main/webapp/swagger-ui/index.html

```
var apiUrl = "http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui/index.html";
```

I get "Can't read from server. It may not have the appropriate access-control-origin settings."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See Jerome's fix on https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/277 by changing gruntfile.js to include below lines in connect/proxies section

```
,{
context: '/api-docs',
host: 'localhost',
port: 8080,
https: false,
changeOrigin: false
}
```

Comment: I have this problem too but I don't even use gruntfile.js. : /

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and found out the the generated classes have the package `com.mycompany.myapp.config.apidoc` but they actually are under `com.mycompany.myapp.apidoc`.

You can solve this by moving the java files to the correct package `com.mycompany.myapp.config.apidoc`.

Comment: I had to do that as well because I was getting Java compile errors. After moving to config.apidoc I am getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable CORS for that sake just add these 3 res.header lines into your API then CORS will be enabled when your accessing that API so that you will not get error like access-control-origin settings.

```js
app.get('/swaggerJson', function(req, res){  
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Cache-Control, Pragma, Origin, Authorization, Content-Type, X-Requested-With");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, PUT, POST, OPTIONS");      
  res.json(swaggerJSON);
});
```

Hope this will help you..

Comment: I don't think you wanted to make that a runnable snippet because it doesn't run

Comment: I have not written entire code so that it ll give error..   "Can't read from server. It may not have the appropriate access-control-origin settings." this is majorly because of CORS to solve this issue have to add the headers to enable access-control-origin settings to your api...