# ASP.NET Core Swagger not working in Chrome with CORS error

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, swagger-ui

I've been following the help for [ASP.NET Web API Help Pages using Swagger](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/tutorials/web-api-help-pages-using-swagger.html) and I receive the following error in Chrome:

- Can't read from server. It may not have the appropriate access-control-origin settings.

It works in IE10 however it doesn't appear to pick up changes.

I found the following entry [Can't read swagger JSON from http://localhost:9000/api-docs/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23252589/cant-read-swagger-json-from-http-localhost9000-api-docs) unfortunately it refers to changing it under grunt when it now works under gulp.

I've also tried to change the CORS setting in ASP.NET core:

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add framework services.
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration);

        services.AddMvc();

        // Inject an implementation of ISwaggerProvider with defaulted settings applied
        services.AddSwaggerGen();


        services.ConfigureSwaggerGen(options =>
        {
            options.SingleApiVersion(new Info
            {
                Version = "v1",
                Title = "Status API",
                Description = "A simple example ASP.NET Core Web API!",
                TermsOfService = "None",
                Contact = new Contact { Name = "A Persone", Email = "some-support@some-company.com", Url = "http://www.some-company.com/" },
                License = new License { Name = "Use under LICX", Url = "http://url.com" }
            });
        });

        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("AnyOrigin", builder =>
            {
                builder
                    .AllowAnyOrigin()
                    .AllowAnyMethod();
            });
        });
    }

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();

        app.UseApplicationInsightsRequestTelemetry();

        app.UseApplicationInsightsExceptionTelemetry();

        app.UseMvc();

        // Enable middleware to serve generated Swagger as a JSON endpoint
        app.UseSwagger();

        // Enable middleware to serve swagger-ui assets (HTML, JS, CSS etc.)
        app.UseSwaggerUi();

        app.UseCors("AnyOrigin");

    }
```

Unfortunately that doesn't make any difference.

Suggestion on how to solve it by changing the gulp settings or the .NET changes would be very welcome

Comment: 1. AddCors only adds the dependencies, it do not add the middleware. That's what you do with UseCors. Do you use UseCors? 2. If you do, whats the configuration of it? 3. Do you run two separate applications on two different ports? IE threats same host+schema but different port as same origin, Firefox and Chrome don't. 4 does it happen on all requests or only on requests other then get? One of the browsers doesn't sent preflight before sending a request, dunno anymore which one it was 5. do you get exception from the server? Exception middleware removes CORS headers from the request

Comment: I'm running the swagger UI on localhost:8080 and the API on localhost:17237

Comment: Then your CORS settings are wrong. Show your CORS policy you used. Like I said, IE treats different ports as same origin and doesn't apply the same origin policy

Comment: I also tried adding the following code which unfortunately didn't help: app.UseCors(builder =>
             builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                    .AllowAnyHeader()
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
             );

Comment: But where is the UseCors called? Before or after UseMvc? Order matters, because the request will be processed by the middlewares in the order they were registered with the `UseXxx` calls. And when using `new CorsAuthorizationFilterFactory("AllowSpecificOrigin")` you also need to add a policy of the same name

Comment: Ah, its clear now. Like in the last comment, UseCors must be used earlier, before swagger or mvc middleware is called

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually this should do the trick, you just need it to have the same policy name. I don't think adding the filters is necessary, if you want to apply it to all requests/routes.

```cs
// ConfigureServices
services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AnyOrigin", builder =>
    {
        builder
            .AllowAnyOrigin()
            .AllowAnyMethod();
    });
});

// Configure
app.UseCors("AnyOrigin");
// Register other middleware here, like UseMvc or UseStaticFiles, depending on if you 
// want StaticFiles to be affected by cors or not you put it before or after the UseCors call
```

**Update**

Like mentioned in the comments above, the middlewares are executed in the order in which they are registered. The request reaches your APi controller before the Cors middleware ever receives it.

Your Configure method has to look like this instead:

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
    loggerFactory.AddDebug();

    app.UseApplicationInsightsRequestTelemetry();

    app.UseApplicationInsightsExceptionTelemetry();

    // it must be placed before UseMvc and before or after
    // UseStaticFiles, depending on if you want the static files to be 
    // Cors enabled or not 
    app.UseCors("AnyOrigin");

    app.UseMvc();

    // Enable middleware to serve generated Swagger as a JSON endpoint
    app.UseSwagger();

    // Enable middleware to serve swagger-ui assets (HTML, JS, CSS etc.)
    app.UseSwaggerUi();
}
```

Comment: I actually tried doing this before and again but I still get the same problem. I'm not sure if its because swagger isn't going through the same middleware, though it is running on the same port

Comment: I also changed ConfigureServices to make it more secure and just what I needed for Swagger:               services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("AllowSpecificOrigin",
                    builder => builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:8080"));
            });